# Can Non- Recurring Profile be created using PayFlow Pro

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox, payflowpro

I would like to know whether there is any functionality of creating non-recurring profiles in PayFlow Pro. To be more clear what I need is when an user registers in my website I need to create an account in PayFlow Pro (please note I dont need a recurring profile). to store the card details as I cannot store the credit card details in my account. And based on this I hope I will return some ProfileID, using this ProfileID I want to display at-least some part of that credit card number(credit card number showing in the format 4576XXXXXXXXXX9098 is fine for me). Is there any such option available in PayFlow Pro.

Answer (score 1):

If you run an Authorization or a Sale transaction you'll get a transaction ID back.  You could then use that transaction ID with [DoReferenceTransaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) to process a future payment using the payment data that PayPal stores on their server.

There is not any way to obtain any part of the credit card number, though.  There is no "profile" per say.  If you need that you'd need to save just the last 4 digits in your own database so that you can display, but I'm not 100% sure how PCI compliance treats saving even the last 4 digits only, so you'll need to look into that.